# Issue with ref parameter in SqlParameter - C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datareader, ref

I am using following code for fetching customer details using Stored Procedure

```
    public List<Customer> GetPacketReconciliation(int customerId, int size, DateTime billDate, ref DateTime lastRunDate)
    {
        List<Customer> getCustomer = new List<Customer>();

        SqlParameter[] arParms = new SqlParameter[4];
        arParms[0] = new SqlParameter("@Cust_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        arParms[0].Value = customerId;

        arParms[1] = new SqlParameter("@Size", SqlDbType.Int);
        arParms[1].Value = size;

        arParms[2] = new SqlParameter("@Last_Run_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        arParms[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
        arParms[2].Value = lastRunDate;

        arParms[3] = new SqlParameter("@Bill_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        arParms[3].Value = billDate;


        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(this.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(sqlCon, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.GetCustomer", arParms))
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {

                    getCustomer= MapToEntityCollection<Customer>(reader);
                }
            }
        }

        if (arParms[2].Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            lastRunDate = Convert.ToDateTime(arParms[2].Value);
        }

        return getCustomer;
    }
```

Store Procedure

```
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomer] 
   @Cust_ID SMALLINT, 
   @Size INT,
   @Last_Run_Date DATETIME OUTPUT,
   @Bill_Date DATETIME
 AS
  BEGIN
  END
```

Here i am using one `ref` variable `lastRunDate`. When debugging i can see that `lastdate` value is setting properly in `sqlparameter`.But when i view it using sql profiler,i can see that `lastRunDate` is setting as `null`.if i hardcode it like arParms[2].Value = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-01") ,it works.Any issue with reference parameter ??

Anyone seeing any issue in this code ..

Comment: How is the stored procedure defined?

Comment: I didn't get u Nino.."Outside" ??

Comment: sorry, I didn't read question carefully enough. How is stored procedure defined, as Lasse asked?

Comment: Show your stored proc

Comment: I want to use LastRundate as InputOutput parameter. bcoz using it for passing value to stored procedure and also value will be reset it in stored procedure

Comment: If you declare a parameter as OUTPUT it acts as input as well as output parameter. So you can pass input value as well. ParameterDirection.InputOutput maybe you need to change this code To Output type